# Count of Work Days Between Two Date Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, subquery

I am trying come up with a number of work days off a delivery was. NOTE: I cannot define a function.

I have a table with delivery details a such:

```
+--------+---------------+---------------+
| Rec_Id | Date_Received | Date_Promised |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 1      | 2020-07-01    | 2020-07-07    |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 2      | 2020-07-15    | 2020-07-08    |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
```

And I have a work day table as follows (T means it is a workday):

```
+---------------+----------+
| CALENDAR_DATE | WORK_DAY |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-01    | T        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-02    | F        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-03    | F        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-04    | F        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-05    | F        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-06    | F        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-07    | T        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-08    | T        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-09    | T        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-10    | T        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-11    | F        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-12    | F        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-13    | T        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-14    | T        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2020-07-15    | T        |
+---------------+----------+
```

The result would look like:

```
+--------+---------------+---------------+----------+
| Rec_Id | Date_Received | Date_Promised | Days_Off |
+--------+---------------+---------------+----------+
| 1      | 2020-07-01    | 2020-07-07    | -1       |
+--------+---------------+---------------+----------+
| 2      | 2020-07-15    | 2020-07-08    | 5        |
+--------+---------------+---------------+----------+
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join, or a subquery, and conditional logic:

```
select 
    d.*,
    case when d.date_received > d.date_promised
        then (
            select count(*) 
            from work_days w 
            where 
                w.work_day = 'T' 
                and w.calendar_date >= d.date_promised 
                and w.calendar_date < d.date_received
        )
        else (
            select - count(*) 
            from work_days w 
            where 
                w.work_day = 'T' 
                and w.calendar_date >= d.date_received 
                and w.calendar_date < d.date_promised
        )
    end as days_off
from delivery_details d
```

You can move the conditional logic within the subquery to shorten the code a little - although I suspect that it might be less efficient:

```
select 
    d.*,
    (
        select case when date_received > date_promised then 1 else -1 end * count(*) 
        from work_days w 
        where 
            w.work_day = 'T' 
            and (
                (w.calendar_date >= d.date_promised and w.calendar_date < d.date_received)
                or (w.calendar_date >= d.date_received and w.calendar_date < d.date_promised)
            )
    ) as days_off
from delivery_details d
```